# Remove element from Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am currently making a tiny little program that should be able to select a random element i put into the array using a Random of course (For practice purposes) and when a element in the array has been chosen at random. i want to remove this element in the array, so how do you remove a element in a array the easiest way?

Its the only thing i want to know. I got everything else sorted. It's just removing the element it has chosen (the random takes a random number between 0 and the amount of elements in the array, so if it chooses 0, it will take the first element in the array, and so on)

Comment: take a new array, copy all elements from original array into new array except the index which is to be removed...
or Use ArrayList and call the remove function....

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which support remove or add function, which actually is an resizable array.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove an element from an array. You can replace it with some other value that indicates "nothing", null for example.

Comment: Thats exactly what i am looking for. I guess i could make it so if Random selects a Null object. It just goes one more time. Until it dosnt find a null right?

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to convert the array into a list.

```
list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Remove any element from the list and then revert it back to an array using

```
array = list.toArray();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use List instead of Array, and if you want to stay on Array than there is 2 solution,

1. Create another Array ignoring your element which you want to delete.
2. create a List using Array.asList(...) than remove element from list and convert back to Array.

but according to me its better for you as well as java to use List. because List provide a many build-in  functions.